# Followers structure in firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement followers functionality in my android application.

1. First image refers to the list of user i followed.
2. Second image have all ids of all the posts that users post
3. Third image havin post details.

All I want to do is to load only the post of those users that i've followed.

What I'm doing is, I get emails from followers node and by using indexed `recyclerview`

I load the data but it's not working because `recyclerview` is not getting dynamic reference.

Any sugested solution ?

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.co)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GYVc.png)

[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kFkE.png)

Comment: Your first picture has a broken link. Please update your post.

Comment: @AlexMamo i dont have enough ratings so i post new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434927/followers-structure-firebase-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Followers structure firebase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434927/followers-structure-firebase-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your user table in following manner. I believe your posts table is correct but you can remove my_posts or if you want to use your than just replace the posts array with the my_posts id.

```
 {
   "users": {
        "xlkfdjklahsf231": {
              "userId": "xlkfdjklahsf231",
              "userName": "userName",
              "posts": {"posdId1", "postId2",.....}
              "followedUser": { "userId1", "userId2" ...},
        },
        "xlkfdjkl123jljasd": {
              "userId": "xlkfdjkl123jljasd",
              "userName": "userName",
              "posts": {"posdId111", "postId222",.....}
              "followedUser": { "userId5", "userId12" ...},
        },
     }
  }
```

You need to query as follows:

```
 private void getUserById(String userId) {
    firebaseRef.child("users")
            .equalTo(userId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This will give you the user from the table
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: if i follow your structure then how can i retrieve the all postids of only those users that i followed ??

Comment: @Ali Haider  you need to query for user from the followedUser array which has the userId; Example; firebaseRef.child("users").equalTo(userId1){.....}; where userId1 is the followed user and get the posts array which will give you all the posts

Comment: @AliHaider you can even just put followerId and userPostId in the user table and create a separate table for array of followerId and userPostId

Comment: Just as a comment. Unless posts and followedUser are sub-collections anytime you query the document you will get all the users followers and posts (could be millions). So if you want to get the users userName, you will get a million followers as well.