# Followers structure firebase android

Tags: android

I want to implement followers functionality in my android application. 'First' image refers to the list of user i followed. 'second' image have all ids of all the posts that users post and 'third' image havin post details. all i want to do is to load only the post of those users that i've followed.

What i am doing is, i get emails from followers node and by using indexed recyclerview i load the data but its not working because recyclerview is not getting dynamic reference. Any sugested solution ?

first

[image]

second

[image]

third

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do more precisely? Which data you want to get?

Comment: i want to get the posts from only those users that i followed

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to query your database for three times like this:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
String encodedUserEmail = userEmail.replace(".", ",");

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userEmailFromFollowersRef = rootRef.child("followers").child(encodedUserEmail);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String followerEmail = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference my_postsRef = rootRef.child("my_posts").child(followerEmail);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String postId = dSnapshot.getKey();

                        DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("posts").child(postId);
                        ValueEventListener vel = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String postText = child.child("postText").getValue(String.class);
                                    Log.d("TAG", postText);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        };
                        postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(vel);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            my_postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userEmailFromFollowersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```